# Leaking valve (kohler)

Tags: leak, faucet, valve

[image]I'm replacing the kohler valve for bathroom faucet (hot water). However, this part shown in the picture is leaking. I tried with plumber tape which helps but doesn't stop the leaking. Can anyone tell me what should I do?
Thanks!

[image]
The left pipe is the one I'm working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an issue like this once in a different application. What I did was add a washer under the nut, from the back side. You can usually get a thin rubber washer to stretch around the flare and inside the nut. Other options would be to make sure the nut isn't broken or been over tightened to many times causing scratching and scoring either on the nut or flare surface, or the flare being squished to many times and flattening it out or bending it strange. You could possibly even put a rubber washer between the flare surfaces of each pipe.

Comment: Make sure the nut isnt split/torn even a little, and also ensure there is not any calcium or other deposits on the seat of the nut of the lip of the valve stem flare. Inspect it for debris or damage.

Comment: Update: I agree that adding a washer should help. I screwed this nut really tight and the water leaks through the lower nut. I couldn't add the washer b/c the connection was so tightened up. If I force it, the pipe may mis-shape. I clean up the debris carefully as noybman suggested. And then apply the plumber's tape. Screw it tight. Now, if I turn on water for one minute, there is about one drop of water. That's good enough for me as a super amateur.

Comment: It would not be good enough for me! After a short time there will be water in the bottom of the cabinet rotting the wood and attracting bugs. To get the fitting apart you will need 2 wrenches about the same length so you can apply equal pressure to both fittings. If you can't do it call someone who can. Any leak is a "disaster waiting to happen"

Comment: You are right! I thought it would only leak when faucet is turned on. But it's not. It leaks a small pod of water overnight. I'll keep trying.

Comment: I would ask a friend or neighbor that uses tools to help.